# End tag for body not found and unclosed div elements

Tags: wordpress, html

Here is the problem that is been bugging me for 2 days now. My website which is running on Wordpress, was working just fine until i've added 1 new article; after that the template gets messed up and after running a validation on w3.org, it says that i'm missing an end tag for  and 2 unclosed  elements.

Now the strange thing is this. **When i remove (unpublish) one article**, **the template is working again just fine.**. But when i publish that article back, the validation errors reappear.

I've eliminated the possibility that that the error is a result of an unwanted html code (accidentally) included in the editor, but I cant find whats causing this error.

Can someone, please, help me out? I'm running out of ideas :(

My website: http://www.vantagemag.com/
The validation code: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vantagemag.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: The main site by itself is not of much use. You need to see what's wrong with the template.

Comment: can't someone understand whats wrong from the source code?

Comment: The template looks fine in my browser (chrome). What issue has the template exactly?

Comment: the sidebar moves to the bottom of the page (instead of right side) and unclosed <body> and <div> elements appear.

@Kev please check this page to see the correct position of the sidebar http://www.vantagemag.com/cat/news/

Comment: I've had a look and ran it with google chrome dev tools. It would seem that there is a quotation mark in an article or something to that effect and the browser is picking it up as markup. It could also be that UTF8 encode is incorrect in the function wordpress is using. Try and re-submit the offending article with normal font from lorem ipsum and see if that resolves it. That way we narrow down the cause and can come up with a solution.

Comment: I've tried an empty article with just a title "test" but the error is still there. Earlier i've unpublished the newest article (the one that was triggering the problem, i've duplicated another article which seemed fine, but the error was triggered again. 

The error seems to appear only in the frontpage of my website, and appart from the main slider, all other elements are the same as in categories

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, an earlier article had  elements in the code, which my client didn't see when he was posting that article. Now i've removed all unwanted elements and everything is back to normal.

Thank you all for the responses and for your time!